# Sitecore testing licenses

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I currently work for a company that uses allot of Sitecore servers and has many dev seats across Europe.

A problem that I have run into is that we desperately need a testing environment for Smoke Testing, Automation Tests and other Manual pre QA deployment.

The internal department that deals with licenses says that kind of environment is classed a a full server and requires the full license fee (which has allot of zeros!!)

Because its an enterprise business we are now in a catch 22 situation. I have heard that spinning up a new VM on the machine I am developing on is allowed on a developers license / and I can reusue my developer license on any machine as long as i am the only person that uses it.

So, if our tester sets up his own test machine that only he uses, its covered by his developer license? That thing will be rebuilt several times a week and never have anybody else connect to it really, maybe other developers. (license overlapping?)

Anybody have any similar issues or solution? I need to provide formal proof if I have any chance of pushing this forward. (I contacted sitecore also but it may take a while for them to come back, Just looking too see if anybody else may help in the mean time)

Comment: Totally depends on your licensing agreement, and whether you are a Sitecore partner. You would have to wait for Sitecore to confirm I'm afraid.

Comment: So it is as complicated and expensive as it sounds? Can a developer use his license on two machines though if its just him using them?

Comment: Yes they are a business partner.

Comment: Doesn't have to be complicated or expensive, but only Sitecore can confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore 8+ licensing structure has changed and will allow you to create multiples of Virtual Machines using a single license. This can be leveraged for test systems, load balancing, pre-production or quality assurance uses.

> IMHO: The only reason they did this was to probably get onto the
>   "cloud" marketing train and realised their 1990's extremely restrictive licensing terms
>   needed to be overhauled  as it prevented them selves from using their
>   own software in virtual machines.

So prior to Sitecore 8, No. You have to have a full license for each machine and each machine.

Basically extremely restrictive licensing that cost a fortune, as that is the Sitecore business model.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this same scenario with several clients who did not purchase licenses for their test servers but are now wondering if their developer seats can cover this. I have always recommended that a separate server license be procured and not to attempt to use the developer seat.

You state that you need a 'formal' proof. That can only be obtained from your Sitecore sales rep. They are usually very quick to respond to clarify licensing questions on what your particular licensing agreement covers for your organization.

If you are working with an implementation partner, they may also be able to help you understand your licensing, but in most cases they would still need to confirm with your Sitecore sales rep.

Comment: Thanks. I am just an independent C# developer that got pulled into this Sitecore madness. I did email sitecore as a normal non client asking for advice, but not heard anything from them. What you saying is that they need a full server license even though its not client facing? A bit odd and very counter productive :(

Comment: Sitecore licensing generally has production and non-production server licenses, as well as developer seats that are usually part of the overall license package obtained by a client. Whomever is on your team that can liaise with the Sitecore sales rep that is handling your company's account is where you should start so you can find out what you can do with what has already been purchased. You may even discover that a test environment or license already exists :)

Comment: Sitecore licensing is madness and it surprises me when companies go "Just ask how much you want"! The whole 'server' concept is 
crooked and again... it is working for them!

Comment: It should be noted that this answer and question is from 2016. Since this time, there has been the introduction of 'subscription' pricing which also has unlimited usage, you now pay for environments. It is a great improvement to free up teams to deploy the architecture they need without having to constantly check against limits.